# Drupal update failed

Tags: drupal

Just updated my Drupal to the latest version. 
However, something must have broken because now all I see is this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventHandlerEntityBundle' not found in /home/<USERNAME>/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/node.rules.inc on line 147`

Any ideas as to what is going wrong and how I can roll back? I can still access the website's CPanel but I have no idea as to what I can do from here.

Comment: Just upload the files and DB backup you have from before the updating. You **do have one**, right?

Comment: The DB was backed up but not the files.

Comment: I'd save a full copy of the site in its current form, and would try to see which files are different from a fresh drupal install...

Comment: Quicker way - get the [Registry Rebuild module](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) and follow the instructions on that page. Same thing happened to me earlier today after updating Rules and that fixed it straight up.

Comment: I used Registry Rebuild. Then, using Update.php takes me to Requirement Problems from where I cannot go any further.

Comment: I had run into the same problem. I ran drush updatedb and now it is working fine. Try the 'drush updatedb' and see how it goes. Run 'drush cc' and clear all cache first.

Answer (score 6):

The suggestions above didn't work for me. I followed the advice on the Drupal site [here](https://drupal.org/node/2090511), which tells you to update the rules module & db independently before attempting your Drupal update.

I ran:

```
drush dl rules
drush updatedb
```

which fixed the Rules update independently; then I could upgrade other contrib modules and Drupal OK.

Comment: If the `drush updatedb` doesn't work you might try rebuilding the registry. That solved my issues on sites where simply updating the db wasn't enough.
`drush rr` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known error that was meant to have been fixed with Rules 2.5 but is still happening with Rules 2.6 as I just experienced it.

First of all, for future reference , I would advise you to use version control, such as Git, which makes it easy to rollback in case of install errors.

I tried to follow the various recommendations as seen in this post
https://drupal.org/node/2090511

I wasn't able to run , although it seems to work for some users

```
drush updatedb
```

On the other hand, doing the database upgrade via the admin interface fixed the problem.

```
yoursite.com/update.php
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue related to rules, it was because I had not completed the database update.  Performing the db update update.php page fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reinstalling an older version of the Rules module (deleting my existing module and uploading the new files).  I installed [7.x-2.3.](https://drupal.org/node/190124/release)